# Wait cursor stuck even after application is idle until mouse is moved

Tags: wpf, cursor

(My WPF code is actually in a DLL and is being launched and interacted with by non CLR code, so this is not qutie a standard WPF application. I've never seen this behavior in a pure WPF app, but I'm not sure if the problem has something to do with that or not)

If my view model is changing rapidly for a period of time and the UI thread is spending a significant amount of time trying to keep up with it (I have several converters and some complicated layouts that have to refresh when the VM changes, e.g. DataGrids resizing their columns when rows are added, etc.), a wait cursor is automatically displayed (by the OS I guess) I've done nothing in my code or XAML to change the cursor. It's also not the same wait cursor you get when you set the cursor to `Cursors.Wait` in WPF. It's the arrow cursor, but it has the wait circle beside it.

I'd prefer this not to happen as the program isn't really "waiting". Most everything is going on in a background thread, the UI thread is just spending a lot of time trying to keep up with it, however the UI is not unreponsive. More anoying is that this cursor stays on even after the application (including the background threads) becomes idle - until the mouse is moved. As soon as the mouse is moved it goes away, but if the user doesn't move the mouse he may inadvertantly think the application is still busy when in reality it is completely idle.

No manner of setting of the cursor with WPF functions have been able to override this cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out for at least hiding the wait cursor once the application becomes idle (but only because my view model explicitly knows when this happens, in a more complicated situation the VM might not be aware of when itself is 'idle')

```
using System.Windows.Input;

...

Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
```

But I'd still like to get rid of this wait cursor in the first place, which is impossible with this method without leaving `Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow` set which means cursor never changes when it needs to (like chaing to ibeam when hovering over textbox, etc).